# Is there a global PHP variable for all requests?

Tags: php, global-variables

I would like to know if it exists a variable  shared between all requests.
I want to use this as cache for application options to avoid to query database or files for every requests.

In other languages (not scripting) I can use a "context variable" or shared objects like services and so on. Is this impossible in php and everything is isolated between requests?

Please consider that I don't want the $_SESSION variable, because it can be shared between the same session and I'm looking for something shared for all requests.

Comment: No there isn't. With PHP, you need to provide persistence, whether using a database, filesystem, shared memory, caching system (like reds or memcache)

Comment: php was designed as a shared-nothing architecture: that's one of the advantages of using php

Comment: It is common to use Memcache or Redis for dynamic server variables - they are lightweight and fast. Of course, if your shared variables are reasonably static, they could be stored as a JSON file and read in when required.